# 'myMethod' does not have a class type

Tags: c++

I'm getting this error `50:23: error: ‘d.Deck<T>::pullCard [with T = Card]’ does not have class type`

I'm pretty new to C++. Line 50 is the call to d.pullCard in main(). Tried to make this using my Java knowledge, but this language seems much more strict.

blackjack.cpp

```
enum Suite { S, H, C, D };
string symbols[] = { "♠", "♥", "♣", "♦" };

class Card
{
    Suite suite;
    int value;

    public:
        Card(Suite s, int v) { suite = s; value = v; }
        Suite getSuite() { return suite; }
        int getValue() { return value; }
        string toString() { return symbols[suite] + " " + to_string(value); }
};

template <typename T>
class Deck : public vector<Card>{
    public:
        Deck(){
            for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) push_back(Card(S, i+1));
            for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) push_back(Card(H, i+1));
            for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) push_back(Card(C, i+1));
            for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) push_back(Card(D, i+1));
        }
        void shuffle(){
            srand(unsigned(time(0)));
            random_shuffle(begin(), end());
        }
        Card pullCard(){
            int index = rand() % 52 + 1;
            Card r = this[index];
            erase(index);
            return r;
        }
};

int main(){
    Deck<Card> d;
    d.shuffle();
    for (int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++) cout << d[i].toString() << endl;
    cout << d.pullCard.toString();
}
```

Comment: `Card r = this[index];` is a mistake, this will do an out of bounds memory access, you meant `(*this)[index]` to call base class's `operator[]`

Comment: It would be better C++ design to have the `vector<Card>` be a member variable (preferably private)

Comment: Thank you. You solved an error I didn't even know I had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling the `pullCard` function. You need to change this:

```
d.pullCard.toString();
```

to this:

```
d.pullCard().toString();
```